# Получение значения словаря map без изменения словаря и ключевое слово const

Tags: c++, map, const

Как известно, если обратиться к словарю `map` по ключу, которого нет, то этот ключ появится. Для того, чтобы оставить словарь без изменений, можно использовать метод `at()`, тогда в случае отсутствия этого ключа, сработает исключение. На основе этих соображений я сделал два примера, один из которых не компилируется. 
Первый вариант - константный метод класса, который обращается к приватному словарю.

```
class Test{
public:
    int GetValue() const{
        return map_.at(2);
    }
private:
    map <int, int> map_ = {{1,2}};


};
```

Для ситуации, если я хочу реализовать функцию, в которую я передаю словарь по константной ссылке, такое обращание через `at()` не пройдёт.

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
Value &GetRefStrict(const map <Key, Value> &input, const Key &key_){
   // map <Key, Value> tmp = input;
    if(input.count(key_) == 0){
        throw runtime_error("This key not exist");
    }
    return  input.at(key_);
}
int main() {
    map<int, string> m = {{0, "value"}};
    string& item = GetRefStrict(m, 0);
    item = "newvalue";
    cout << m[0] << endl; // выведет newvalue
  return 0;
}
```

Если же я удаляю `const`, эта функция сможет скомпилироваться.

Comment: В чем ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гм!

```
int Test2(const map<int, string> &input){
    return input.at(2);
}
```

`at()` возвращает значение - так? Т.е. `string`. А вы возвращаете из функции `int` - но разве есть оператор приведения типа `string` в `int`?..

**Update**
Судя пор вашему коду, вы хотите в константном `map` изменить значение, получив на него ссылку. Как минимум, вы хотите просто обмануть компилятор...

См. https://ideone.com/yPz59g - получите `const string`, но менять через него значение нельзя!

Comment: вы абсолютно правы. Столкнулся с этой проблемой, когда шаблон писал и тут сделал ошибку. Изначально в другом коде поймал ошибку. Прикрепляю к посту.

Comment: заменил последний кусок кода.

Comment: Ну вас не удивляет, что нельзя создать, например, ссылку на неконстантное значение для константы? Типа `const int a = 5; int& i = a;`? Тогда почему вы удивляетесь, что при попытке вернуть неконстантную ссылку на константное значение из функции у вас траблы?

Comment: разве я не получил ссылку на этот элемент словаря, а затем уже по этой ссылке изменяю значение?

Comment: Вы получаете для константного объекта константную ссылку и не можете с ее помощью менять объект! В этом же весь смысл константности! Хотите менять объект - не передавайте его как `const`. Элементы - это же составная часть объекта.

Comment: Спасибо, понял!